# PHP: If no rows

Tags: php

```
if ( $bid != $USER OR mysql_num_rows($already) > 0) {
    echo "ok";
}
```

I have this line. I want "ok" to show, if $bid isn't the same as $USER OR if there doesn't exists any rows in the $already query.

What have I done wrong?

```
function show_block_Form($bid, $id, $USER){
$already = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_blocked WHERE bID = '$bid' AND uID = '$USER'") or die(mysql_error());
if($bid != $USER || mysql_num_rows($already)==0){
echo "ok"
}
}
```

Comment: Well, what happens when your run it?

Comment: Please explain what does those lines mean in your script or we will not be able to understand if it right or wrong!

Comment: He's given enough information for us to help him with this. There's not more that he can explain, without going into all the details of his specific project.

Answer (score 1):

> I want ok to show, **if $bid isnt the
>   smae as $USER** **and** if **there doesnt
>   exists any rows in the $already query**.

```
if($bid != $USER && mysql_num_rows($already) <= 0){
```

Comment: You can then change it to or :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($bid != $USER OR mysql_num_rows($already)>0){
```

should be

```
if($bid != $USER || mysql_num_rows($already)==0){
```

Comment: I meant OR.. I tried to do OR mysql_num_rows($already)==0 it still shows OK

Comment: I fixed it; that's what I thought you meant but I wasn't sure.

Comment: okay, just tried that, it still shows. I tried to echo num_rows $already, and it outputs 1 so there is one row but still shows even with this restriction?!

Comment: My bet is that this is wrong: `$bid != $USER`. Try echoing `$bid` and `$USER`

Comment: Ok update i just checked the if arguments. If i remove $bid != $USER, the num_rows works, if i remove num_rows the $bid != $USER works.. It cant handle two arguments at same time?

Comment: $USER is 1, yes, that's me.. it works fine ^ read above comment, i cant use OR?

Comment: Make sure you are using `||` instead of `OR`.

Comment: I am, i copied exactly your line

Comment: Well unfortunately there's not much more I can tell you without seeing the rest of your code. This line is fine; these isn't anything else you can do to fix it. Some other part of your code is causing issues.

Comment: Impossible I only have $already query and then the function name above this?

Comment: upadted question with the function

Comment: Again, I can't really do much more to help you. The line does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Also, please be sure you are escaping your inputs (`$bid` and `$USER`)

Comment: It should be able to handle any amount of conditionals. It must be the underlying logic which you are trying to implement that is incorrect.